# How to stored images in the cookies using the angular

Tags: angular

I am using the ngx-cookie-service in the angular for static website project, how to stored the images in cookies, and stored images get the other component.

Comment: [ngrx](https://ngrx.io/)  and [ngxs](https://ngxs.io/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store a link to an online image in the cookie is more efficient, and probably you can use that instead. Can you?

Each time a webpage is browsed, the unnecessary bandwidth will be taken by an image stored in the cookie. In case of too many images it could be even worse. But if you have few images then you can store in `src/assets/images` folder and access them directly by setting the path in image URL.